# Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

All of a sudden my website is throwing this error message when I try to debug it within Visual Studio. If I deploy the website, it works without any errors.

Any suggestions to resolve this error.

```
[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946132
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Answer (score 42):

Try delete that section from your `web.config`

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: @AllmanTool Many thanks, you saved my day. 
Could you please explain why we need to delete this section?

Comment: Hello Chau Than, Actually i don't know :) I think it someting with depency redirection. I once encountered with such issue and found this answer on the Internet

Comment: This worked for me too after my API wouldn't debug any more all of the sudden (I upgraded an in-house NuGet package).

Comment: I had to delete lots of stuff..., 10 to 15 maybe..., but it eventually works. 

Comment: This helped me after upgrading from 4.6.2 to 4.8

Comment: Deleting that section in my web.config did the magic. Worked for me

Comment: This helped me! although I then had to work through each of the items that were coming up as a failure. but this got it moving for each case.

Answer (score 12):

Delete the `\bin` and `\obj` directories,  Rebuild your project.

Comment: This worked for me. I switched target-framework, so the `Clean` ignored files in \bin folder that were messing with my project.

Comment: This did it for me. Clean Solution did not work. I had to delete the \bin directory. I recently did a major update of packages in my solution so that must have had something to do with it.

Comment: I had to delete the /obj folder too to work.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, but with `System.Runtime` specified in the error message:

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]

I found that thoroughly cleaning the solution and rebuilding fixed this problem for me.  And just doing a Visual Studio Clean wasn't enough.  I actually had to delete my `\bin` folders as well.

Comment: For me this was on deployment.  I had not cleaned out existing dlls, and was getting BadImageFormat as well.  Clearing out everything and re-deploying fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with .NET Core, and have this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Then, switching it to this is a potential solution:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: I had this issue with `System.Data.SqlClient` and was able to resolve it by installing the package from NuGet. The [reference assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies) must've gotten referenced somewhere instead of the 'real" one.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  Your solution helped point me in the right direction for my .NET Core 3.1 app.  In my case, I was also using NLog with a database target.  After correcting the reference, I had to take an additional step to set dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", and now I am good to go!  Ref: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#dbprovider-examples

Answer (score 1):

Another potential reason we could get this error is if we actually ARE using a [reference assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies).

> Reference assemblies are a special type of assembly that contain only the minimum amount of metadata required to represent the library's public API surface....Because they contain no implementation, reference assemblies can't be loaded for execution. Trying to do so results in a System.BadImageFormatException.  -learn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my dll was only 1.0, and the error box said 4.0

I went back to NuGet Package Manager and put in System.Management.dll 4.0 —

no luck, then I just went back and put in System.Management.dll alone (as I remember), and it came up with a 5.0.  Not exactly sure how I prompted it to do so, but it seemed quite willing.

Installed, works!

Answer (score 0):

The same error happen in my case when I attach my DLL's from the "[build folder]\ref" folder.

It should be referenced from the [build folder]. (Net5)