# Azure failing Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure, umbraco

I have been getting this error for a while now.

[image]

Oddly I only get this error when I publish the app to to Azure, locally it's fine.

I've tired changing the redirect to:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I've looked online and so fair no luck.

The app it's self is a Umbraco site using framework 4.7.2

Any help would be great!

UPDATE - 
I put System.Net.Http as a reference to my web project and set the copy local to true, this means the DLL was published but now I'm getting the error:

[image]

I've tried to add the following:

```
 <add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

And I've also tried this:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange issue with System.Net.Http 4.2.0.0 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570912/strange-issue-with-system-net-http-4-2-0-0-not-found)

Comment: I've been through that but it didn't help :(. I don't understand why this only happens on my Azure web app and not locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing all references to System.Http.Net, uninstalling it from NuGet, deleting the DLL form ( (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib)

Then I installed it again via NuGet but the latest version and removed all the additional binding redirects from the web.config.

This then fixed the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this should be fairly easy: in your `web.config` find the compilation\assemblies section and add the `System.Web.Http` assembly there under `System.Net.Http`:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Another thing that might help, if you get errors compiling your code, try referencing `System.Web.Http` version 4.2 and setting the **build action** to **copy local**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://umbraco.com/blog/getting-a-systemwebhttpapicontroller-error/#comment-10380).

Comment: Hi Joey, Thanks for the reply! I've tried adding in the assembly, do I also need the binding redirect? I have set copy local to true but it never goes into the bin folder so when I publish it's missing from the root of my azure app bin folder. Does that make sense?

Comment: After setting copy local to true, have you rebuilt your project? When it appears in bin folder and then you publish it will work well.

Comment: Hey, to give a bit more background, I have a class library that uses it and a web project that references that library. I added System.Net.Http as a reference to to web project and copy local to true, it now sends the DLL to the server when I publish, but I'm getting another error, I'll update the ticket so you can see

Comment: Try delete that section from your web.config. Refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207137/reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-execution/42997402).

Comment: I've just tried but I still get the same error, I can;t seem to add it via nuget, when I install the package and try to use HtttpClient() it says I need a ref so I put one in but it comes from my local one.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere, It's now saying there's an error with Umbraco because it want's System.Net.Http version 4.0.0.0