# VS2019 Must DELETE /bin folder and recreate in order for solution to debug

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

I have a VS2019 ASP.NET (MVC 5) Solution with which I must delete and recreate the /bin folder in order for the solution to compile and debug. Once I delete it, it runs fine until I restart (close/open VS & the project) and attempt to debug again.

I began getting this error with a move from Framework 4.6.2 to 4.8. All updates are current.

I get the following error when I begin a debug session:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
...

[BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.]

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
```

So the first thought is permissions, but all looks correct. Running the solution in admin does NOT change anything. I've repaired VS2019 but still to no avail.

I have a few other projects that run stable on Framework 4.8, although it was a bumpy ride getting them there, but for different reasons.

Has anyone experienced this and if so what fixed it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just to be safe: Have you run a full _Build: Clean Solution_? I assume you have. But, if not, that cleans up the `/Bin` folder _as well as_ the `/Obj` folder. Sometimes, metadata files get created in the `/Obj` folder which _may_ impact what gets copied over to `/Bin`. It's at least _conceivable_ that outdated manifests could be recreating the problem each time you build or debug. Though, I'd definitely be curious what specifically is causing this error.

Comment: @JeremyCaney thanks for your reply. Yes -- I usually do a Clean Solution followed by a rebuild solution. Maybe overkill but it'more habit than anything. Also I've deleted the /obj folder too so that would be rebuilt also, but to no avail. So you don't think it's permissions either, do you?

Comment: I'm really not sure, to be honest. Though other similar reports, with other assemblies, don't seem to be resolved by changing the permissions ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207137/reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-execution)), so I doubt it. Personally, I'd spend some time evaluating solutions to the general exception, independent of `System.IO`, and see if any of the fixes work for your case. Many of the suggestions I've seen related to this error don't appear to be assembly specific. For

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to load one of the shim DLL's (which contain only interfaces and class definitions with no implementation, part of the .NET Standard mechanics) vs. the actual implementation DLL.  A couple things: 1) have you tried closing VS and deleting the '.vs' folder next to the .sln?  2) have you tried deleting/commenting out any bindingRedirects in your web.config?